# I have a segmentation fault and am unsure about what is wrong with my code

Tags: c, list, pointers, nodes, cs50

Any guidance would be appreciated. I personally believe the problem lies in the load method. Also, the basic functionality of each method is written in the comments. What could be the cause of my segmentation fault? and Is everything working as intended? Thank you for your time.

Any resources that may point in me in the proper direction would be appreciated too.

```
 /**
 * Implements a dictionary's functionality.
 */

#include <stdbool.h>
#include "dictionary.h"
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <cs50.h>

//Defining node:
 typedef struct node
 { //Inner workings of each "element" in the linked lists
    char word[LENGTH + 1]; //the word within the node is +1'd due to the memory after the word containing /0
    struct node *next; //linked list
}node;



  node *alphabetList[27]; //26 buckets that can contain variables of type node(of dynamic size)
//one bucket for each letter of the alphabet
  node *cursor = NULL;
  node *head = NULL;

/**
 * Returns true if word is in dictionary else false.
 */
bool check(const char *word)
{
    int bucketIndex ;
    //no need to malloc information b/c we are simply pointing to previously established nodes.
    if(word[0] >= 65 && word[0] < 97){
        bucketIndex = word[0] - 65;
    }
    else{
        bucketIndex = word[0] - 97;
    }


    node *head = alphabetList[bucketIndex];

    node *cursor = head;

    while(cursor != NULL)
    {
        cursor = cursor -> next;
        if(strcmp(cursor -> word, word) != 0)
        {
            return true;
        }

    }


    return false;
}

/**
 * Loads dictionary into memory. Returns true if successful else false.
 */
bool load(const char *dictionary)
{
        char *word = NULL;
        int i = 0; //index
        FILE *dictionaryTextFile;
        dictionaryTextFile = fopen(dictionary, "r");

        //scan for word
        while(fscanf(dictionaryTextFile, "%s", word) != EOF)
        {
            //for every word we scan we want to malloc a node to ascertain we have sufficent memory
            node *new_node = malloc(sizeof(node));
            if(new_node == NULL) //error check(if you run out of memory malloc will return null)
            {
                unload();
                return false;
            }
            //error check complete.
            else{
                strcpy(new_node -> word, word);
            }


            //not sure from here on 
            char first_letter = new_node[i].word[0]; //first letter of node word (confused on how to execute this properly)

            first_letter = tolower(first_letter);
            int index = first_letter - 97;

            if(word){

                for(node *ptr = alphabetList[index]; ptr!= NULL; ptr = ptr->next)
                {
                    if(!ptr-> next){
                        ptr->next = new_node;
                    }
                }

            }
            else
            {
                alphabetList[index] = new_node;
            }
            i++;
            }


     return true;

    }





/**
 * Returns number of words in dictionary if loaded else 0 if not yet loaded.
 */
unsigned int size(void)
{
    return 0;
}

/**
 * Unloads dictionary from memory. Returns true if successful else false.
 */
bool unload(void)
{
    for(int i = 0; i <= 26; i++)
    {

    node *head = alphabetList[i];
    node *cursor = head;

    while(cursor != NULL)
    {
        node *temp = cursor;
        cursor = cursor -> next;
        free(temp);
    }

    }
return true;

}
```

Comment: What is the problem you're having? Does the `load` function not work? What is it meant to do that it isn't currently doing? Based on the limited information provided it looks like it should do what you want.

Comment: Sorry for wording it incorrectly originally. Basically, the load method has to take information from the dictionary file and then allow the rest of the program to utilize it. I am getting a segmentation fault as well and I am not sure as to where it should be. I was wondering if using [i] to go through the node would reach my desired conclusion as well

Comment: Run your code in a debugger (ie gdb). It'll tell you where the segmentation fault is happening. That's a vital piece of information you need to add to your question

Comment: When I run it in the cs50 debugger on cloud9 it tells me my issue starts at line 70 (the start of the while loop). Thank you for your time by the way I appreciate it.

Comment: Also, is my for-loop written well enough? I've been paranoid thats another mistake of mine. Sorry this is the first time I've been stuck on a program and I'm a little crazy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is obvious now you've said on which line the code crashes. Consider these lines...

```
    char *word = NULL;
    int i = 0; //index
    FILE *dictionaryTextFile;
    dictionaryTextFile = fopen(dictionary, "r");

    //scan for word
    while(fscanf(dictionaryTextFile, "%s", word) != EOF)
```

You've got 2 problems there. Firstly, you don't check that the call to `fopen` worked. You should always check that the value returned is not `NULL`.

Secondly, and the cause of the crash, is that `word` is still `NULL` - you don't allocate any space to hold a string in it. You might as well declare it the same as you declare it inside `node` so replace

```
    char *word = NULL;
```

with

```
    char word[LENGTH+1];
```

Speaking of `node` and to save you coming back with another crash later, you should always make sure you initialise all attributes of a struct. In this case `new_node->next` should be set to `NULL` as otherwise you'll come to check it later in your `for` loop (which looks fine BTW) and it might appear to point to a node, but it's pointing at some random place in memory and the code will crash.

Comment: I rewrote it and solved it, thanks for caring friend :)